# Django redirecting to incorrect URL

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am working on the login/logout functionality of a basic Django website. (CS50's Pinocchio's Pizza). The logout path is being injected into the URL & I am unsure as to why. My navbar links to the home page, yet when I click on it it redirects me to the logout page. Any other link I click, that link's path is added to the URL but attached to the logout path. 
For example, clicking on the login button of my site, whose path is `login_default`, the url becomes:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/logoutlogin_default
```

Trying to click the link in the navbar that should link to the `index` page gets me:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout
```

The folder "orders" is an app which "pizza" is made aware of. All html pages are inside `orders/templates/orders`.

This is `orders/urls.py`

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name = "index"),
    path("register_default", views.register_default, name = "register_default"),
    path("register_setup", views.register_setup, name = "register"),
    path("login_default", views.login_default, name = "login_default"),
    path("login_setup", views.login_setup, name = "login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
]
```

In `pizza/urls.py`, the Orders app's URLs have been made known:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("orders.urls")),
    path("register_default", include("orders.urls")),
    path("register_setup", include("orders.urls")),
    path("login_default", include("orders.urls")),
    path("login_setup", include("orders.urls")),
    path("logout", include("orders.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

This is `orders/views.py`

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    # If user is not logged in
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "orders/index.html", {"message": None})
    context = {
        "user": request.user
        }
    return render(request, "orders/index.html", context)

def register_default(request):
    return render(request, "orders/register.html")

def register_setup(request):
    firstName = request.POST["userFirstName"]
    lastName = request.POST["userLastName"]
    email = request.POST["userEmail"]
    pw = request.POST["userPW"]

    user = User.objects.create_user(firstName, email, pw)
    user.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

def login_default(request):
    return render(request, "orders/login.html")

def login_setup(request):
    username = request.POST["loginName"]
    password = request.POST["loginPW"]

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "orders/login.html", {"message": "Invalid Credentials"})

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return render(request, "orders/login.html", {"message": "Logged Out"})
```

This is `base.html`, which all other templates are based off of.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light">
        <a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="navbar-brand">Pinocchio's Pizza</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">

            {% if message %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="nav-link">Log Out</a>
            </li>
            {% else %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{% url 'login_default' %}" class="nav-link">Log In</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{% url 'register_default' %}" class="nav-link">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

This is `login.html`

```html
{% extends "orders/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Log In{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% if message %}
<h1 class="text-danger">{{ message }}</h1>
{% endif %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto mt-4">
            <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="loginName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="loginName" id="loginName" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="loginPW">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="loginPW" id="loginPW">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Log In</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is `pizza/settings.py`

```py
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i0&iq&e9u9h6(4_7%pt2s9)f=c$kso=k$c$w@fi9215s=1q0^d'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'orders.apps.OrdersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pizza.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pizza.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Could you include you base `urls.py` file. The one that redirects to `pizza/urls.py`, `orders/urls.py`, etc

Comment: The default base `urls.py` file when I downloaded was `pizza/urls.py`. Do you recommend a different structure?

Comment: I didn’t catch that. I’ll write an answer that I think will help.

Comment: The project's distribution code is https://cdn.cs50.net/web/2019/x/projects/3/project3.zip in case you would like to look at it & see the file structure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `pizza/urls.py`to the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("orders.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

the reason is the `""` path should automatically include all the urls in `orders.urls`. Here is a link to the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Another thing that I noticed that helps catch bugs is to include a `/` at the end of urls so in your `orders/urls.py` you can change it to the following.

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name = "index"),
    path("register_default/", views.register_default, name = "register_default"),
    path("register_setup/", views.register_setup, name = "register"),
    path("login_default/", views.login_default, name = "login_default"),
    path("login_setup/", views.login_setup, name = "login"),
    path("logout/", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
]
```